# What is supposed to change after editing a question in response to the suggested duplicate prompt?

Tags: support, duplicate-suggestions

When someone suggest a duplicate for your question (either via flag or close-vote) you have the opportunity to select whether the linked question answers your question or not. If you select that it doesn't, the following message appears:

> Thanks! Edit your question to explain how it's different from the suggested questions. This will help prevent your question from getting closed and will remove the suggested questions notification from your post.

[image: Screenshot of message]

I am confused by the last part, since, as far as I can tell, nothing changes after editing the question. The suggestion in the post itself linking to the related question disappears as soon as you select that it's not a duplicate, even if you don't edit the question. The auto-comment with the duplicate suggestion remains even after editing the question. So what exactly does this refer to?

Comment: Same here, that's confusing / misleading.